# Rails script tag syntax error?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Running my Rails app on a new host and was upgraded to Ruby v2.0.0 from 1.9.3, and I'm getting this weird syntax error. It looks like this:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 178ms                                                                                                                              

ActionView::Template::Error (/home/action/braindb/app/views/folders/_contents.html.erb:124: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input):             
121:                                                                                                                                                                  
122:        </script>                                                                                                                                                 
app/views/folders/show.js.erb:1:in ` _app_views_folders_show_js_erb__1073772573694008441_69985052296980'                                                                 
app/controllers/folders_controller.rb:34:in `show'
```

I'm not sure what's wrong with my `<script>` tags, so I'll paste the file (_contents.html.erb) here:

```
    <div id="panel-container">
    <div id="entry-container" class="entry-window">
        <div id="meta-bar" class="top">
            <span id="location-span" style="position:relative; float:left;">In <%= @folder.title %></span>
            <div id="entry-meta" class="meta-info">
                <i class="icon-remove icons top-icons" id="close"></i>
                <i class="icon-ok icons top-icons" id="save-entry"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="entry-create-partial" class="contain-entry">
            <div id="title-create-partial" class="title-partial" name="title" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder='Title it' style="color:black"></div>
            <div id="content-create-partial" class="content-partial" name="content" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder='Write anything' style="color:gray"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="right-panel" class="resize">
        <div id="top" class="top">
            <div id="folder-left">
                <h3><%= @folder.title %></h3>
                <% if @folder.children.count + @folder.submissions.count == 0 %>
                  Empty! Add journals & entries
              <% else %>
                  <%= @folder.children.count %> Journals & <%= @folder.submissions.count %> Entries
              <% end %>
            </div>
            <% end %>
            <ul id="inner-list">
                <button class="btn" id="journal-create-button">New Journal</button>
                <div id="create-journal-drop">
                    <form action="/folders" method="post">
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %> 
                        <%= hidden_field_tag :parent_id, @folder.id %>
                        <h3 id="journal-create-partial">New Sub-Journal</h3>
                        <input type="text" id="titleinput" name="title" placeholder="Title it">
                        <button type="submit" class="md-close folder-create" id="folder-create">Create</button>
        </form>
                </div>
                <button class="btn" id="entry-button">New Entry</button>
    </ul>
        </div>
        <% if @folder.submissions.count > 0 %>
        <svg id="submission-circles">
            <circle></circle>
            <circle></circle>
            <circle></circle>
            <circle></circle>
        </svg>
        <% else %>
        <h2>It's quiet in here. Create a journal entry or sub-journal to get started!</h2>
        <% end %>
    </div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    d3JSON = function(){
        d3.json("/folders/<%= @folder.id %>.json", function(error, data) {

            var circle;

            var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg");

            circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(data.submissions, Array);



            circle.enter().append("svg:a")
            .attr("xlink:href", function(d){
                return "#";
            })
            .append("circle")
            .style("fill", "#c0392b")
            .attr("id", function(d){ return d.id; })
            .attr("data-name", function(d){ return d.title; })
            .on("click", function(d) {
                if (d.children !== null) {
                    console.log(d.children);
                    $.get("/parent_submissions/", {submission: d.id}, null, "script");
                }else{
                    $.get("/new_submission/", {submission: d.id}, null, "script");
                }

            })
            .attr("cy", 90)
            .attr("class", "floating")
            .attr("cx", function(d){
                return (d.content.length / 2) * 10 + "px";
            })
            .attr("r", 50);

            $("svg circle").tipsy({
                gravity: 'w',
                html: true,
                title: function() {
                    var d = $(this).closest("svg circle").attr("data-name");
                    return d;
                }
            });

            circle.exit().remove();

        });
    };
    entryAJAX = function(){

        $("#save-entry").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/submissions",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {title: $("#title-create-partial").text(), content: $("#content-create-partial").text(), folder_id: <%= @folder.id %>},
                complete: function(){
                    $.get("/ajax_load_events/", {folder: <%= @folder.id %>}, null, "script");
                }
            });
        });


    };

</script>
```

Right now these Javascripts are at the bottom of my _contents.html.erb file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after close de `div#folder-left` and before `ul#inner-list` you have an `<% end %>` but I can't find a block starting to him...

I missed something or you missed something?